# Would graphite stick to basalt cooled from its molten state in a graphite mold?

Tags: materials, intermolecular-forces

Molten metal that is poured into a graphite mold pops out easily once it has cooled. Would basalt poured the same way pop out just as easily?

I am particularly interested in lunar basalt, if that makes any difference. The image shows the composition used to make a lunar regolith simulant, taken from [chapter 13](http://www.uapress.arizona.edu/onlinebks/ResourcesNearEarthSpace/resources13.pdf) of [Resources of Near Earth Space](http://www.uapress.arizona.edu/onlinebks/ResourcesNearEarthSpace/contents.php), by B. J. Pletka.

[image: chemical composition of lunar mare basalt]

Comment: What are you going to melt that mixture in? It would seem that it would dissolve a ceramic or clay crucible.

Comment: @MaxW i was thinking graphite, with some tungsten reinforcement.

Comment: graphite burns in an oxidizing atmosphere. In a reducing atmosphere many of the metal oxides could react to form the metals. I'm sure that making such mixtures has been done before. I'm just curious...

Comment: @MaxW i'm figuring this out as i go along. I don't know anything about it, it's for a simulation of a lunar colony. Could the furnace be tungsten? The molten mixture would be poured in the open, so it is a vacuum environment. Oh, also, maybe if the temperature isn't higher than what is needed to melt the feedstock, say 1200 C, maybe there wouldn't be enough oxygen liberated for it to be an issue?

Comment: If the idea is to make bricks from basalt then the lunar sand would be sintered not melted.

Comment: @MaxW that isn't the idea. http://moonwards.com/index.html - click #5 of the second image for a very brief initial write-up. The concept needs lava in high volume. Sintering methods are a bit finicky, they need to be finely controlled, not very workable for a tele-operated approach.

Comment: If you put tungsten in contact with graphite it will form tungsten carbide

Comment: @A.K. a quick look at its properties doesn't make that seem like a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it would not stick. In our lab we commonly use graphite dishes/cups/etc to contain small amounts of liquid rock. All you need to do then is to hold it upside down and the solidified rock (now glass mostly) falls out. Sometimes there's a bit of graphite dust on it, but it can be easily scraped off.

Doing it in a reducing (or oxygen-free) environment will make it even easier, because graphite slowly burns to carbon dioxide with time, on the scale of hours, from my own personal experience.